# Format a date string while using .map to create a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am using .map with React to create a table based on a `coupons` object. Trying to format a date string to "mm/dd/yyyy" format. `coupon.starts_at` is typically `coupon.starts_at = "2013-08-03T02:00:00Z"`

I think I am declaring the function in the wrong spot.. where am I going wrong in organizing this?

```
import React from 'react'

export default ({ coupons, edit }) =>

<div className="row no-gutters">
    <div className="col-3 Col TitleCol">
      <h3 className="sub-heading">Existing Coupons</h3>
    </div>
    <div className="col-9 Col ContentCol">
      <table className="settings-table stack">
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Code</th>
              <th>Discount</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Start Date</th>
              <th>Expiration Date</th>
              <th></th>

         </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {
            coupons.map(coupon =>
                <tr key={coupon.id}>
                    <td>{coupon.code}</td>
                    <td>{coupon.discount}</td>
                    <td>{coupon.description}</td>
                    <td>{formatDate(coupon.starts_at)}</td>
                    <td>{coupon.expires_at}</td>
                    <td className="remove nowrap">
                      <span className="ahref" onClick={(event) => {event.preventDefault(); edit(coupon.id)}}>Edit</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )
        }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  {
    let date = new Date(coupon.starts_at);
    function formatDate(date){
      let year = date.getFullYear();
      let month = date.getMonth()+1;
      let day = date.getDate()+1;
      if (day < 10) {
        day = '0' + day;
      }
      if (month < 10) {
        month = '0' + month;
      }
      date = month+'/'+day+'/'+year
      return date;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The brackets around the definition of `formatDate` are almost certainly messing things up, as is the line `let date = new Date(coupon.starts_at);`. Remove those and you should be in a better state

Comment: Awesome - Thanks. Got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a new Date(date) to wrap the string to a Date object and it should be ok.

```html
{
    let date = new Date(coupon.starts_at);
    function formatDate(date){
      let year = date.getFullYear();
      let month = date.getMonth()+1;
      let day = date.getDate()+1;
      if (day < 10) {
        day = '0' + day;
      }
      if (month < 10) {
        month = '0' + month;
      }
      date = month+'/'+day+'/'+year
      return date;
    }
```

Comment: Or you can do it in your function. :)

Comment: Thanks! :) Forgot to do that but unfortunately it still doesn't solve the issue. It fails to compile because Line 29:  'formatDate' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 42:  'coupon' is not defined      no-undef.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. :) It runs very well in my side.

```js
let date = new Date('2013-08-03T02:00:00Z');
    function formatDate(date){
      let year = date.getFullYear();
      let month = date.getMonth()+1;
      let day = date.getDate()+1;
      if (day < 10) {
        day = '0' + day;
      }
      if (month < 10) {
        month = '0' + month;
      }
      return month+'/'+day+'/'+year;
      }
      
 console.log(formatDate(date));
```